# VS Code multiple taskbar icon

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have more projects opened, is there a way to have them separated in the Windows taskbar? Until recently I was using 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to achieve this, but that program stopped working after a Windows update. Does VS Code have such a checkbox somewhere to not group icons in the taskbar but to have them separated? I don't want this for all the applications, only for VS Code.

For better understanding I attach a picture. What I would like is to have that many items in the taskbar as many instances open, not to be merged in one taskbar icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set this in Windows, but the 7+ Taskbar Tweaker has that possibility. Since the time I asked this question, 7+ Taskbar Tweaker was updated and now works perfectly. All good, THX.

Comment: I needed the exact thing. Maybe I'll save somebody else googling time. This can be done in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker by using Taskbar Inspector -> Change application ID

Comment: @vondravl You can actually right click on the `Microsoft.VisualStudioCode` group in the Taskbar Inspector and select "Combine: Never" to get the same result.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if what you are asking is possible, probably if what you want to do is to identify each project and not get confused, you could use **Peacock.**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock

Comment: This is a handy extension indeed.

Comment: Now, if only there's a way to change the taskbar icon color as well... I'll be depending on spatial memory for now.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click taskbar
- Taskbar settings
- Combine taskbar buttons > Never (or "when taskbar is full")

[Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfZbc.png)

[How it becomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5rha.png)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want this for all the applications, only for VS Code. I use 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to achieve this, it works now well.

Answer (score 0):

you can change combine taskbar to never to separate windows on taskbar in windows taskbar settings.

[image]

Comment: This is the same answer like the one below, where I replied: `Thank you, but I don't want this for all the applications, only for VS Code.`